# Application to remove GPS metadata from pictures

Tags: osx, images, gps, exif

I'm in need of finding a piece of software that can easily strip GPS information from a picture without having to jump through too many hoops.  I know I can use Photoshop to open and then resave a photo as a new file; however, that can become very tedious (unless I create an repeatable action in Photoshop). I've also tried Preview but that doesn't make the job any easier either as far as I can tell.

Nonetheless, I'm looking for a simple piece of software that when given one or more pictures, it simply strips any GPS information.

The software should do the following:

1. Given a folder or set of images it removes GPS metadata from the picture
2. Provides an option when saving the picture(s) to either: a) overwrite the original image or b) save the pictures to another location with a custom naming convention that can be selected by the user

Other helpful features, but not required would be:

1. ability to resize pictures upon saving
2. ability to add a watermark
3. ability to add copyright metadata to the image

Answer (score 1):

[GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/key-features/batch-conversion-with-additional-functions/) is a $40 shareware application for image editing and manipulation that has lots of features geared towards batch operation and image meta data manipulation. It's quaintly referred to as the swiss army knife of image editors and I believe that's a very accurate description. It can import more than 200 different types of image forms and export more than 80. It has extensive batch processing capabilities (resize, crop, add meta data, adjust levels, etc).

To address your questions specifically-

1) You can remove all EXIF or IPTC information from images in batch mode. There is not an option for removing geotags (but you could zero them all out I suppose if you wanted to keep other EXIF information).

2) Batch mode supports saving into the same directory (it will prompt you to overwrite or rename) or into a new directory.

3) Batch mode has numerous crop / scaling options. Importantly, on the scaling options you can specify the scaling algorithm ([here's some information on why selecting the appropriate scaling algorithm is more important than people think](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-resize-for-web.htm)).

4) Depending on what kind of watermark you are looking for you have a variety of options. In batch mode you can add regular text (with a user specified font, placement, etc) or you can also insert an image (such as if you have a watermark logo) on top of the images being processed.

5) In batch mode you can add your own EXIF or IPTC information.

GraphicConverter has been around in the Mac community for quite a number of years and is continually well maintained and is overall a good native Mac application (supporting Services, HiDPI, etc). I've owned it since the late 90s and found it well worth the very reasonable price. A time limited demo can be downloaded from [Lemke Software](http://www.lemkesoft.de/en/order/) (you can then buy a license in-application) or you can just purchase it in the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/graphicconverter-9/id736099092?mt=12).